# Manage SQL query multidimensional array output as stdClass Object

Tags: php, sql, arrays, object, stdclass

I using an MVC framework with controllers and routes on PHP 5.6.

I am trying to define some PHP variables from the database.

```
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
| meta_id | post_id |  meta_key   |  meta_value   |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
|    3506 |     147 | event_flag  | 1             |
|    3507 |     147 | event_year  | 2019          |
|    3508 |     147 | event_title | Soccer Encore |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

Here I call the query.

```
// Controller:
public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_data['checklist_content'] = $this->_models['wp_stream_settings']->getChecklistMeta(147);
    }
```

Here is the query:

```
// Model:
function getChecklistMeta($item_id){ // passed $item_id = 147
     $sql = '
        SELECT *
        FROM '.PREFIX.'wp_postmeta
        where post_id = '.$item_id.' and meta_key IN ( "event_flag", "event_year", "event_title" );
    ';
    return $this->db->select($sql, array(':ID' => $item_id));
}
```

This query will give all the information needed and put the variables in an stdClass object:

```
// Data
[checklist_content] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [meta_id] => 3506
                [post_id] => 147
                [meta_key] => event_flag
                [meta_value] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [meta_id] => 3507
                [post_id] => 147
                [meta_key] => event_year
                [meta_value] => 2019
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [meta_id] => 3508
                [post_id] => 147
                [meta_key] => event_title
                [meta_value] => Soccer Encore
            )
    )
```

But I can not manage the array as I want:

```
echo $data['checklist_content']->{'event_title'};
```

I tried to use array_search:

```
print_r(array_search("event_title",$this->_data['checklist_content']));
```

with no avail.

I could modify the SQL query in order to have more manageble stdClass object, or maybe remapping it in a JSON format, or else.

How can I modify the query or else, in order to get something like this:

```
// Data
[checklist_content] => Array
    (
        [event_flag] => 1

        [event_year] => 2019

        [event_title] => Soccer Encore

    )
```

So that I could easily display the value "Soccer Encore" like this:

```
echo $data['checklist_content']->{'event_title'};
```

for now I am forced to get the variables like this:

```
echo $data['checklist_content'][2]->{'meta_value'}; // Outputs "Soccer Encore"
```

I am open to redesign the query or even to use a JSON method or a serialisation to be able to mange better the variables.

Comment: As advice for general system design, you should split that table into three different tables or hold all the data in one row. Holding all the information for a certain post in one table with multiple rows is _very_ costly.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP >= 7.0.0 get `meta_value` and index it by `meta_key`:

```
$result = array_column($data['checklist_content'], 'meta_value', 'meta_key');
```

Then:

```
echo $result['event_title'];  //displays Soccer Encore
```

If you need to preserve other properties:

```
$result = array_column($data['checklist_content'], null, 'meta_key');
```

Then:

```
echo $result['event_title']['meta_value'];  //displays Soccer Encore
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but for PHP 5.6. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct but only working for PHP70, for PHP56 I solved the problem creating an additional array using a **'for loop'** inserting `meta_key` and `meta_value` pairs from the messy array `$this->_data['checklist_content']` :

```
// Data
[checklist_content] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [meta_id] => 3506
                [post_id] => 147
                [meta_key] => event_flag
                [meta_value] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [meta_id] => 3507
                [post_id] => 147
                [meta_key] => event_year
                [meta_value] => 2019
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [meta_id] => 3508
                [post_id] => 147
                [meta_key] => event_title
                [meta_value] => Soccer Encore
            )
    )
```

and added them to a new stdClass array: `$this->_data['campaign_settings']`.

```
<?php
// order stdClass data. parse data pairs (meta_key and and meta_value) 
// as new objects in the $this->_data['campaign_settings'] array
for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->_data['checklist_content']); $i++) {
    // create another array pair
    $nameKey = $this->_data['checklist_content'][$i]->{'meta_key'};
    $valueKey = $this->_data['checklist_content'][$i]->{'meta_value'};
    $this->_data['campaign_settings']->$nameKey = $valueKey;
}
?>
```

the new array shows as follows:

```
Array
(
    [campaign_settings] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_flag] => 1
            [event_year] => 2019
            [event_title] => Soccer Encore
        )
)
```

and these are the desired outputs from this query:

```
echo $this->_data['campaign_settings']->{'event_title'}; // outputs "Soccer Encore"
echo $this->_data['campaign_settings']->{'event_year'}; // outputs "2019"
echo $this->_data['campaign_settings']->{'event_title'}; // outputs "1"
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert stdobject of database to json use json_decode
It convert object into2d array

Comment: `json_decode` decodes (not encodes) object and the result of `json_encode` is not "2d array", it is JSON string